# Python ImportError: cannot import name mpManager - why this happens? NO circular import

Tags: python, python-import

I have a package-wise variable defined under pyspookystuff/mav/**init**.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import logging
import multiprocessing

import time


# existing has to be thread safe


# class DronePoolDepletedException(PyspookyException):
#     pass

mpManager = multiprocessing.Manager()

....
```

When I import the variable mpManager in another package (pyspookystuff/mav/comm.py):

```
import json
import os

import dronekit
import re
import sys

from pyspookystuff.mav import utils, mpManager
```

It throw the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peng/.IntelliJIdea2016.2/config/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 71, in patched_import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/peng/git/datapassport/spookystuff/mav/pyspookystuff/mav/comm/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pyspookystuff.mav import utils, mpManager
ImportError: cannot import name mpManager
```

Why this happens and how to fix it? I'm using Python 2.7

**UPDATE**: I insert the sys.path discovery line before the line that throws the import error:

```
print(sys.path)
```

This is the result of running `python -m unittest discover` directly (bypassing IntelliJ IDEA/Pycharm runner):

```
['/home/peng/git/datapassport/spookystuff/mav', '', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/peng/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 240, in serve_client
    request = recv()
  File "/home/peng/git/datapassport/spookystuff/mav/pyspookystuff/mav/comm/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pyspookystuff.mav import utils, mpManager
ImportError: cannot import name mpManager
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Looks totally normal, is it helpful in trying to find the bug?

Comment: Sounds like a circular import to me. Show us a [mcve].

Comment: run your python script with "-v" for verbos prints, that can help u debug the imports. such as "$ python -v script.py"

Comment: @user2357112 as you can see none of the imports in package pyspookystuff.mav come from anything under pyspookystuff/mav, so clearly there is no circular import

Comment: @tribbloid: How did you and where did you execute the file `pyspookystuff/mav/comm.py`? Also seems there's an error of the filename `pyspookystuff.mav/__init__.py`.

Comment: @PhilipTzou thanks a lot for pointing it out. filename fixed. It is used by a nosetest case under an entirely different package pyspookystuff_test

Comment: @tribbloid before the line triggered `ImportError`, add `print(sys.path)` and paste the result here.

Comment: @PhilipTzou, done! Please see my update

Comment: you say `I have a package-wise variable defined under pyspookystuff/mav/init.py:`  -  the file should be  `pyspookystuff/mav/__init__.py` instead

Comment: @tribbloid Try run `python -m unittest discover` from folder `/home/peng/git/datapassport`.